# How to draw a line under uiTextField inside uiTableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, core-graphics

I am trying to create text field with only bottom border. The field is placed inside dynamic cell and created using a storyboard. Border style is set to None. Auto Layout is turned on. The line is drawn in `layoutSubviews()`. However, the line doesn't appear. Could you please help me to fix it? Thx in advance!

Here is the code:

```
extension UITextField {

    func drawUnderline() {
        let underline = CALayer()
        let underlineWidth = CGFloat(1.0)
        underline.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        underline.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - underlineWidth, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
        underline.borderWidth = underlineWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(underline)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}



class TextFieldTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var editTextField: UITextField!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.editTextField.drawUnderline() // The line is drawn here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from Interface Builder.Create UIView with fixed height = 1 and give some color (black), make sure to be equal width to textfield,after just connect your UITextField with no border to that view.So vertical space constraint between textfield and view = 0